# CSS: Poner dos botones bootstrap uno al lado del otro

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Los botones se ven así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que reglas de CSS tendría que ponerles para que se vieran uno al lado del otro?

```html
<td>
        <a href="{{ route('admin.admins.show', $admin->id)}}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">View</a>
        <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.admins.destroy',$admin->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrar()">
      <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
      {{method_field('DELETE')}}
     </form>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hazlo así, metelo dentro:

```
<td>
    <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.admins.destroy',$admin->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrar()">
        <a href="{{ route('admin.admins.show', $admin->id)}}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">View</a>
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
        {{method_field('DELETE')}}
    </form>
</td>
```

No creo que te de ningún problema..

Comment: Easy peasy lemon squeezy.. Gracias!

Comment: A veces nos complicamos las cosas demasiado, tan simple como ponerlo dentro del form también, bien visto!

Comment: La etiqueta <td> debería de estar dentro del form también para que funcione, editalo para ayudar a otros usuarios:)

Comment: ¿¿Entonces el table y el tr también lo quieres dentro del form?? porque no puedo poner un form dentro de

Answer (score 3):

Creo que lo que buscas es `display: inline-block`

Intenta hacer algo similar a esto:

```css
.linea
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="linea">Boton1</button>
<button type="submit" class="linea">Boton2</button>
```

Comment: El problema creo que es al estar uno de los dos botones dentro de un formulario, si añado style display:inline-block igual, no estan en linea.